# Adding unique ValidationGroup names to forms

Tags: asp.net, forms, function, validation

I have a problem when adding modules/controls to a webpage in a ASP.NET CMS which have form validation that it would validate all forms on the page, because the ValidationGroup has the same name. How to solve this with a function?

Comment: Apparently i've already answered a similar/duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443516/asp-net-user-control-validation-group-issue (also VB.NET) **Edit**: only just seen that you've also added an answer there :)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with below solution:

A function that iterates through a certain placeholder to assign unique ValidationGroup names to each form.

```
    Public Shared Sub SetValGroupControls(PageModule As Control, valGroupName As String)
      For Each ctrl As Control In PageModule.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is RequiredFieldValidator Then
          DirectCast(ctrl, RequiredFieldValidator).ValidationGroup = valGroupName
        ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is RegularExpressionValidator Then
          DirectCast(ctrl, RegularExpressionValidator).ValidationGroup = valGroupName
        ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is CompareValidator Then
          DirectCast(ctrl, CompareValidator).ValidationGroup = valGroupName
        ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is CustomValidator Then
          DirectCast(ctrl, CustomValidator).ValidationGroup = valGroupName
        ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is RangeValidator Then
          DirectCast(ctrl, RangeValidator).ValidationGroup = valGroupName
        ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is Button Then
          DirectCast(ctrl, Button).ValidationGroup = valGroupName
        End If

        If ctrl.Controls.Count > 0 Then
          SetValGroupControls(ctrl, valGroupName)
        End If

      Next
    End Sub
```

Where PageModule represents the placeholder where the validation controls are contained (to avoid iterating through all controls on the page) and the ValGroupName represents the unique string which will be assigned as name.

Assuming my validation controls are contained in a placeholder that is called 'plhMyForm' you can call the function like this:

```
    Dim nGuid = String.format("{0}-validation", Guid.NewGuid())
    SetValGroupControls(plhMyForm, nGuid)
```

Above will create a unique string like:
**24ad5ae3-fead-4a6f-98f3-dffcd2e815ba-validation**

Of course you can use your own unique string generation.

Now you can leave your ValidationGroup name empty and the function assigns one for you. This way every form on the same page that requires validation will individually validate itself.